# Given a list and a vector, create a new vector where the given vector is appended to the list, without using list->vector or vector->list

Tags: scheme

Basically, what I'm trying to do is supposed to be this:

```
(list->vector (append (vector->list v) lst))
```

Without the use of `list->vector`, `vector->list` or `append`.
My current implementation is as follows:

```
(let* ([vlen (vector-length v)] [len (+ vlen [length lst])] [new-vec (make-vector len)])
    (let loop ([i 0]) (
        (cond   [(= i len) new-vec]
                [(>= i vlen)
                    (vector-set! new-vec i [list-ref lst [- i vlen]])
                    (loop [add1 i])]
                [else
                    (vector-set! new-vec i [vector-ref v i])
                    (loop [add1 i])]))))
```

I'm getting this exception though:

```
Exception: attempt to apply non-procedure #(*newvector*)
Type (debug) to enter the debugger.
```

*newvector* here is the set of values inside the new vector that is supposed to be returned after the list has been "appended" to the vector.

I'm pretty sure the reason I'm getting this exception is because my loop is actually recursing and is trying to return the new vector up the stack, and thus this ends up happening somewhere after the new vector has been created:

```
                ......
                    (vector-set! new-vec i [....])
                    (#(*newvector*))]
                ......
```

And thus Scheme interprets it as a procedure instead of return value.
I've tried different approaches to fixing this but I always end up with a similar result.

Any feedback appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your loop structures seems ok, but is `(#(*newvector*))` part of the source? (that looks wrong)

Comment: @soegaard Nah, it is just a placeholder for an arbitrary set of values.

Answer (score 0):

Use vector-append from srfi 43.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is for an assignment and the instructor only uses Chez Scheme R5RS.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I'm still not sure what exactly was wrong in my first implementation but chunking my named let up into two helper methods seems to work:

```
(define (vector-append-list v lst)
    ;(list->vector (append (vector->list v) lst))
    (let* ([vlen (vector-length v)] [len (+ vlen [length lst])] [new-vec (make-vector len)])
        [copy-from-vec v new-vec]
        [copy-from-list lst new-vec [vector-length v]]
    )
)

(define (copy-from-vec v nv)
    (if (zero? [vector-length v])
        nv
        (let loop ([i 0])
            (vector-set! nv i [vector-ref v i])
            (if (= (add1 i) [vector-length v])
                nv
                [loop (add1 i)]))
))

(define (copy-from-list lst nv vlen)
    (if (zero? [length lst])
        nv
        (let loop ([i 0])
            (vector-set! nv [+ i vlen] [list-ref lst i])
            (if (= (add1 i) [length lst])
                nv
                [loop (add1 i)]))
))
```